# Postgresql 10 query with large(?) IN lists in filters

Tags: postgresql, performance

I am working on a relatively simple query:

```
SELECT row.id, row.name FROM things AS row 
WHERE row.type IN ( 
'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000031201',
...
 )
ORDER BY row.name ASC, row.id ASC 
LIMIT 2000;
```

**The problem:**

the query is fine if the list contains 25 or less UUIDs:

```
 Limit  (cost=21530.51..21760.51 rows=2000 width=55) (actual time=5.057..7.780 rows=806 loops=1)
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=21530.51..36388.05 rows=129196 width=55) (actual time=5.055..6.751 rows=806 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 1
         Workers Launched: 1
         ->  Sort  (cost=20530.50..20853.49 rows=129196 width=55) (actual time=2.273..2.546 rows=403 loops=2)
               Sort Key: name, id
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 119kB
               ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using idx_things_type_name_id on things row  (cost=0.69..9562.28 rows=129196 width=55) (actual time=0.065..0.840 rows=403 loops=2)
                     Index Cond: (type = ANY ('{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000031201,... (< 24 more)}'::text[]))
                     Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 0.202 ms
 Execution time: 8.485 ms
```

but once the list grows larger than 25 elements a different index is used and the query execution time really goes up:

```
 Limit  (cost=1000.58..15740.63 rows=2000 width=55) (actual time=11.553..29789.670 rows=952 loops=1)
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.58..2400621.01 rows=325592 width=55) (actual time=11.551..29855.053 rows=952 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_things_name_id on things row  (cost=0.56..2362039.59 rows=135663 width=55) (actual time=3.570..24437.039 rows=317 loops=3)
               Filter: ((type)::text = ANY ('{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000031201,... (> 24 more)}'::text[]))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 5478258
 Planning time: 0.209 ms
 Execution time: 29857.454 ms
```

**Details:**

The table contains 16435726 rows, 17 columns. The 3 columns relevant to the query are:

- id   - varchar(36), not null, unique, primary key
- type - varchar(36), foreign key
- name - varchar(2000)

The relevant indexes are:

- create unique index idx_things_pkey on things (id);
- create index idx_things_type on things (type);
- create index idx_things_name_id on things (name, id);
- create index idx_things_type_name_id on things (type, name, id);

there are 70 different type values of which 2 account for ~15 million rows. Those two are NOT in the IN list.

**Experiments and questions:**

I started by checking if this index helps:

create index idx_things_name_id_type ON things (name, id, type);

it did but slightly. 12s is not acceptable:

```
 Limit  (cost=1000.71..7638.73 rows=2000 width=55) (actual time=5.888..12120.907 rows=952 loops=1)
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.71..963238.21 rows=289917 width=55) (actual time=5.886..12154.580 rows=952 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using idx_things_name_id_type on things row  (cost=0.69..928774.57 rows=120799 width=55) (actual time=1.024..9852.923 rows=317 loops=3)
               Filter: ((type)::text = ANY ('{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000031201,... 37 more}'::text[]))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 5478258
               Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 0.638 ms
 Execution time: 12156.817 ms
```

I know that large IN lists are not efficient in Postgres but I was surprised to hit this as soon as 25 elements. Or is the issue here something else?

I tried the solutions suggested in other posts (to inner join to a VALUES list, too change IN to IN VALUES, ...) but it made things even worse. Here is an example of one if the experiments:

```
SELECT row.id, row.name
FROM things AS row 
WHERE row.type IN (VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000031201'), ... )
ORDER BY row.name ASC, row.id ASC 
LIMIT 2000;
```

```
 Limit  (cost=0.56..1254.91 rows=2000 width=55) (actual time=45.718..847919.632 rows=952 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.56..10298994.72 rows=16421232 width=55) (actual time=45.714..847917.788 rows=952 loops=1)
         Join Filter: ((row.type)::text = "*VALUES*".column1)
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 542360414
         ->  Index Scan using idx_things_name_id on things row  (cost=0.56..2170484.38 rows=16421232 width=92) (actual time=0.132..61387.582 rows=16435726 loops=1)
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..0.58 rows=33 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.022 rows=33 loops=16435726)
               ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.41 rows=33 width=32) (actual time=0.004..0.030 rows=33 loops=1)
 Planning time: 1.131 ms
 Execution time: 847920.680 ms
(9 rows)
```

Query plan from inner join values():

```
 Limit  (cost=0.56..1254.91 rows=2000 width=55) (actual time=38.289..847714.160 rows=952 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..10298994.72 rows=16421232 width=55) (actual time=38.287..847712.333 rows=952 loops=1)
         Join Filter: ((row.type)::text = "*VALUES*".column1)
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 542378006
         ->  Index Scan using idx_things_name_id on things row  (cost=0.56..2170484.38 rows=16421232 width=92) (actual time=0.019..60303.676 rows=16435726 loops=1)
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..0.58 rows=33 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.022 rows=33 loops=16435726)
               ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.41 rows=33 width=32) (actual time=0.002..0.029 rows=33 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.247 ms
 Execution time: 847715.215 ms
(9 rows)
```

Am I doing something incorrectly here?

Any tips on how to handle this? 
If any more info is needed I will add it as you guys ask.

ps. The column/table/index names were "anonymised" to comply with the company policy so please do not point to the stupid names :)

Comment: Try [analyzing the table](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Introduction_to_VACUUM,_ANALYZE,_EXPLAIN,_and_COUNT) to ensure its statistics are up to date. Otherwise Postgres can't make an accurate query plan.

Comment: I analysed the table a few times during past few days. And if you look closely this index: idx_things_name_id is used in the query with list size > 25.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the same with me and that is why this is so confusing for me. here joining agains values() is significantly slower.

Comment: @DominikBoszko I see, excuse me.

Comment: As I wrote in the question I tried all options. Joining included. The performance was simmilar to IN. If you wish I can find the explain plan form the join experiment and add it to the question. Update: plan added

Comment: I'm no expert so I probably can't help you, but I find this an interesting question. What happens if you drop the index `idx_things_name_id` which "erroneously" gets used in the 25+ case? Is that even an option for you?

Comment: Why are you casting type to text in slower query?
I saw that in the slower explain... INDEXES needs to be same type or expression.
Can you update with table and indexes structures?

Comment: @Thomas I am working on a clone of a production server so i can remove it as a test. And in fact it does help. The question is why? Unfortunately I will not be able to remove it in production, a number of other use cases get a lot worse without this index.

Comment: @NatanMedeiros 1. All this information was added to the question from the start. What else do you need? 2. The cast is not done by me but comes from the fact that the column is varchar(36) and the uuids in the query are treated as text. This should make no difference according to the docs as in postgress varchar(n), varchar and test are essentially the same. For sure those types should not make a difference when it comes to index usage.

Comment: If all else fails, you can always code your app to perform multiple queries that each stay below the limit of 25, and then merge the results... which makes me wonder: how about trying a UNION of multiple SELECTs that each are below the limit? You might need to fiddle with the SELECTs a bit to prevent the optimizer from merging them back into one big SELECT, but maybe it can be done.

Comment: Please add real DDL (not shorthand) . IMHO your problem is in your (lack of) data modelling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually figured out what is going on. Postgres planner is correct in its decision. But it makes it basing on not perfect statistical data. The key are those lines of the query plans:

**Below 25 UUIDs:**

```
->  Gather Merge  (cost=21530.51..36388.05 **rows=129196** width=55) 
(actual time=5.055..6.751 **rows=806** loops=1)
```

Overestimated by ~160 times

**Over 25 UUIDs:**

```
->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.58..2400621.01 **rows=325592** width=55) 
(actual time=11.551..29855.053 **rows=952** loops=1)
```

overestimated by ~342(!) times

If this would indeed be `325592` than using the index on **(type, id)** which already is sorted as needed and filtering from it could be the most efficient. But because the overestimation Postgres needs to remove over *5M rows* to fetch the full result:

```
**Rows Removed by Filter: 5478258**
```

I guess Postgres figures out that sorting `325592` rows **(query > 25 UUIDs)** will be so expensive that it is more beneficial to use the already sorted index vs sorting of `129196` rows **(query <25 UUIDs)** which it can sort in memory.

I took a peek into `pg_stats` and the statistics were quite unhelpful.

This is because just a few types that are not present in the query occur so often and the UUIDs that do occur fall into the histogram and are overestimated.

Increasing the statistics target for this column:

```
ALTER TABLE things ALTER COLUMN type SET STATISTICS 1000;
```

Solved the issue.

Now the query executes in `8ms` also for UUIDs lists with more than 25 elements.

UPDATE:
Because of claims that the :text cast visible in the query plan is the culprit I went to the test server and run:

`ALTER TABLE things ALTER COLUMN type TYPE text;`

no there is no cast but nothing has changed:

```
`Limit  (cost=1000.58..20590.31 rows=2000 width=55) (actual time=12.761..30611.878 rows=952 loops=1)
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.58..2386715.56 rows=243568 width=55) (actual time=12.759..30682.784 rows=952 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_things_name_id on things row  (cost=0.56..2357601.74 rows=101487 width=55) (actual time=3.994..24190.693 rows=317 loops=3)
               Filter: (type = ANY ('{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000031201,... (> 24 more)}'::text[]))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 5478258
 Planning time: 0.227 ms
 Execution time: 30685.092 ms
(9 rows)`
```

Comment: If you want to do any king of meaningful performance test please at least try to reflect the conditions on the server. The issue here of quantity and bad data distribution (hence bad statistics). You created a table with 300x less data and you seriously are trying to prove something using it? your whole table has twice less rows than Postgress expects to return here!

Answer (score 0):

This is related with how the PostgreSQL choose to use or not the subquery JOIN.

The query optimizer is free to try to decide how he acts (if uses or not indexes) by some internal rules and statistical behaviors and try to do the cheapest costs.

But, sometimes, this decision could not be the best. You can "force" your optimizer to use joins changing the `join_collapse_limit`.

You can try using `SET join_collapse_limit = 1` and then execute your query to "force" to use the indexes.

Remember to put this option on session, normally the query optimizer has right on decisions.

Is an option that worked for me for subqueries, maybe a try inside a `IN` will also helps to force your query to use the indexes.

Comment: This is not useful as the original query I am asking about does not use joins so this property will not affect it. join_collapse_limit does not impact if the index is used. SET join_collapse_limit = 1 prevents Postgress from reordering the joins (so indeed it may affect which index is used but for different reasons!) but this comes into an effect only if there is more than one. And no query in the question has more than one join. But I do thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

> there are 70 different type values of which 2 account for ~15 million rows. Those two are NOT in the IN list

And you address this *domain* using a 36 character key. That is 36*8 bits of space, where only 7 bits are needed.

- put these 70 different types in a separate LookUpTable, containing a surrogate key
- the original `type` field could have a UNIQUE constraint in this table
- refer to this table, using its surrogate id as a Foreign Key
- ... and: probably similar for the other *obese* keys

Comment: Thank you for your input. The distribution here is the data of just one customer. There are over 400 more. We are not able to produce a custom system for each one. Having said that, those 36 char UUIDs are indeed a known problem. The solution was chosen years ago and it is not optimal. Yet this idea of UUIDs as keys has permeated the application so much that it would be incredibly costly to rip it out now.

Comment: Additionally the type is already a foreign key to a different table which contains the type definition (which is written quite clearly in the question). I do not understand what do you hope to get from creating a pivot table between them.

Comment: I do not want to create a pivot table (it is not needed) I just want you to avoid *fat keys*

Comment: We know fat keys are an issue. And we have plans to remove them but believe me, this is not easy. The cost of this operation may far exceed the value. What I can assure you with 100% certainty is that those fat keys are not the main issue here. They will make less stuff fit into work_mem thou and I am checking if this could have an impact

Comment: *plonk* This is just the actual problem.Could be solved in <1h of time.